# How to configure "pages left in this chapter" for EPUBs in iBooks?

Tags: ios, epub, ibooks

As far as I am aware, EPUB3 does not require one chapter to equal one xhtml file although that seems to be a common practice. However, it seems that the "pages left in this chapter" feature at the bottom of the screen assumes that one xhtml file equals one chapter by default.

Does anyone know whether this is configurable?

Currently, I am breaking up a chapter into multiple XHTML files because otherwise the chapter files would be ridiculously long (working on textbook type content). Is there anyway to define what a chapter is in an EPUB when it is composed of multiple files? Is that even what the "pages left in this chapter" feature is tied to?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you can use the EPUB 3 Structural Semantics Vocabulary: http://www.idpf.org/epub/vocab/structure/ to structure your publication.

Note, however, that the current reading systems mostly ignore epub:type values, and, in any case, the "pages left in this chapter" thing is not defined by the EPUB3 specification, hence "defining" it is up to each reading system implementer.